# Image with border and fill

Tags: graphics, text, border, fbox

I'm trying to insert an image with a rectangular border, and that rectangular border has a gray color, something like this:
[image]

This is my code:

```
\begin{figure}
\lineskip=-\fboxrule
\textcolor{Orange}{
    \colorbox{Gray}{
      \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
            \centering
            \includegraphics{imagenes/ejemplo_cubo_OLAP.png}
            \abovecaptionskip=0pt
            \textcolor{Gris}{\caption{\sffamily{\textbf{The caption text}}}}
            \end{minipage}
        }
    }
}
\end{figure}
```

And the result I get is this:

[image]

As you can see, the gray fill is spilling over the edge, and that's what I want to avoid.
Keep in mind that I am very new to Latex

Comment: Any news?  You receive two answer, are none of them meet your expectations? If one do, be so kind and accept it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of this answer).  With this you will inform audience here, the your problem is solved. Also with this you will earn 2 points of reputation :-)

Answer (score 3):

Why not  simply a `\parbox`  in a `\fcolorbox` ?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{figure}[h]\fboxrule3pt\fboxsep2em
\fcolorbox{orange}{lightgray}{%
\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\centering%
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}%
\caption{\lipsum[2][1-2]}}}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1][4-8]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

With use of the `tikz` package and `example-image-duck` instead of original image, which is not available to us:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
figframe/.style = {
    draw=orange, very thick, fill= gray!30,
    minimum width=\linewidth, inner sep=2mm,
    text width= \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width} - 
            2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
    align=center}
        } 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font={small, bf, sf}]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\tikz{\node [figframe]{
        \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{imagenes/ejemplo_cubo_OLAP.png}
        \caption{The caption text}
                      };
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```